# How to automate versioning in kubernetes Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-ingress, versioning, cicd

I have a multiple application deployed on kubernetes with multiple host. I want to configure versioning for the deployed apps. There will be multiple version for each app (/v1, /v2 ...). I have configured a pipeline to deploy app on TAG and created deployment and service for new version But how can I update New tag verison and update it in ingress controller.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: app1.com
      http:
        paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app1
                port:
                  number: 3000
            path: /
          - pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: app1-v1.0.0
                port:
                  number: 3000
            path: /v1
```

How I can Update new version(app1-v1.1.0) in ingress file using automation? Also when I create TAG v2.0.0 it should create new service `app1-v2.0.0 and point the` backend with /v2.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this has barely anything to do with GitLab, except for the fact that you're using it to host your codebase..

---

To answer your question - I would just use [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/). It's already [built into kubectl](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/25/kubernetes-1-14-release-announcement/#notable-kubectl-updates), so no need to install separate packages.

Since it seems like you want to have the same ingress, you'll have to play around a bit and figure it out, because you can't just create a new template for the every tag and overwrite the current ingress.

The way you're requesting it, you'll have to re-generate the ingress manifest, add the route for each tag, and then apply it manifest.

Basically, you'll have to do some scripting - fetch all tags from GitLab's API, and for each of them add a route in your ingress definition.